# Producing a time-lapse video over 6 months or more

Tags: video-recording, time-lapse

I have been asked to produce a time-lapse video from a construction site.

Can anyone suggest a setup and recommend equipment for the following requirements? :

- Must operate outdoors in Scandinavian weather conditions (mixed precipitation, wind, temperatures below zero)
- Should take 1 picture every minute, during working hours (8 hours a day, Mon-Fri)
- Electricity will not be available permanently
- Camera must not be moved (meaning, charging periodically outside working hours could be an option, but without moving the camera)

I hope you have some good ideas :-)

Sincerely,

Jesper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding specific models is outside the scope of this site as the ideal available models will change regularly, but you will probably want to look at a security camera to fill this roll.  Not a lot of cameras are designed to operate reliably in harsh conditions over long periods of time.  Outdoor security cameras are.

The next biggest problem is going to be the lack of power and the cold temperature.  Batteries do not work well at low temperature and if it is below freezing, you are going to see drastic reductions in battery efficiency making it difficult to keep the camera running.

You might also try outdoor hunting webcams.  They tend to be used to take photos at a slower rate and have more battery powered options. These might also work for your purposes.

Comment: You obviously know your stuff, AJ!

Comment: @BrettFromLA - that and Google and I are friends.  I just know enough to know what to look for.  I had heard of hunting related blind cameras before but didn't remember them until I did some research on harsh environment cameras for this question.

Comment: The secrets come out.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Our client just finished up a project using a similar construction time-lapse camera.
https://cam-do.com/blogs/camdo-blog/how-solar-saved-the-topcon-time-lapse-project

Comment: Welcome! [Link only answers are discouraged](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) because if the link becomes unavailable, the answer is lost. Can you provide some context to the link, quote the most important part, or summarize the contents of the link?